# Laravel "Failed to load resource"

Tags: php, css, laravel

i have the blade in this route:

```
/resources/views/cms/public/views/projects/showproject.blade.php
```

And the code to render the picture is this:

```
@if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
    <p class="lead"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.png') }}" width="50%" >Home</p>
@else
    <p class="lead"><img src="/assets/img/projects/{{$project->slug}}/home.png" width="50%">Home</p>
@endif
```

The storage disk called projects looks like here:

```
 'projects' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/projects'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
  ],
```

The error is this:

```
header.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I think the problem is in the code on the view, i also read maybe i need use a symbolic link, isn't possible make it without?

Any help will be appreciated, if have any question ask it please.

Thanks. (I check the others question of stackoverflow before, and can't find the error).

Comment: Try to make the Symbolic Link, everything that is in your `storage` folder, and is loaded from your `public` folder needs to be symlinked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem:

The Public Disk

The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Of course, once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

Comment: Hi Jorn, first of all thanks for your fast answer. When i post the question i was reading too the doc. It was successful, just make `php artisan storage:link` and then `<img src="{{ asset('/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.png') }}" width="50%" >Home`Thanks a lot! Let me ask you something, if i don't know which is the extension, how i should do it? Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: I would store your image name,type,path in your database. If you have images that are part of your design and will stay there for a long time, just hardcode them. If you have pages where you will upload images to or change frequently, store them, so you can retrieve the location, and type from the DB